# Seeking ideas to correct and prevent sprinkler from spraying building

Tags: sprinkler-system

The neighbor is a plant nursery, which use sprinklers to water inventory late at night.  The report is that their sprinklers are watering our building which is an issue.   As I understand it, even if the sprinkler are put back into calibration to avoid spraying the building, it will eventually go out of calibration.

What would be effective techniques to:

1. encourage and put the responsibility on the neighbor to monitor /
   correct?
2. enact physical prevention building spray?

Would a 'backstop' placed directly behind the sprinkler help?  Constructive suggestions are appreciated as I am trying to maintain a good relationship with the neighbor. That being said, humor is appreciated too.

Experience and lessons learned are appreciated: thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming installing a fence is out of the question?

Comment: Sprinkler shield is a real thing!

Comment: A wooden fence exists, however it does not stop the water because the sprinkler's are Montes on a pole to maximize coverage

Comment: They make a hydrophobic coating meant to assure if someone urinates on a wall, it  will bounce back onto their shoes.  Maybe that would help.  Anyway it's in the neighbor's interest to spray correctly, if a head turns, he's parching some of his plants.

Answer (score 1):

A 9 iron oughta take care of it. Wear speedos and have a stogey in your cheek when you take the swing, and don't flinch when the water sprays you in the face. Let's them know you mean business.

Answer (score 1):

When it's off, few tablespoons of cement in the right spot, should do the trick.

Comment: Superglue could be easier, however, I heard that a judiciously placed bucket with a note would be more effective

Comment: @gatorback  Gosh...notes?  I suppose the next thing you're going to suggest is to talk to your neighbor...or something.  Boring!